# Rownum equivalent in Informix SQL?

Tags: select, informix, row

I want to explore (=looking at the first 100 rows) databases using the *Informix* SQL dialect.

- In Oracle SQL I would use `SELCT* FROM table_name WHERE ROWNUM < 100`
- In Postgress SQL I would use `SELCT* FROM table_name limit 100`
- I also tried `SELCT* FROM table_name first 100`

None of these methods works for Informix.

**What I found:**

- When looking at the documentation (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=programming-retrieve-multiple-rows) I only find explanations how it works internally, but not how to do it on the user side.
- This question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119278/row-numbers-for-a-query-in-informix) only covers the issue that rum numbers shall be added to a table.

**One side note:**
the programm I use will do the SQL call on multiple databases and combine the resulting tables in one table.

Answer (score 2):

You can find information about the LIMIT keyword for Informix 12.10 on the IBM site.  There are analogous links for the 14.10 documentation.  The limit can appear in either (but not both) of two different places within an Informix SELECT statement.

- [SELECT statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=statements-select-statement)
- [LIMIT clause](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=statement-limit-clause#ids_sqs_2113)

  - This goes after the ORDER BY clause and before the INTO TEMP clause (if those are present).  Otherwise, it goes at the end of the SELECT statement.
- [Projection clause](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=statement-projection-clause#ids_sqs_0156)

  - You can use `SKIP n` and/or either of `FIRST n` or `LIMIT n` at the start of the 'select list' after the keywords `SELECT`.

Note that you should be planning to move from Informix 12.10 to 14.10.  It is still supported, but it won't be supported forever.

Answer (score 1):

As [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) mentioned:

Online docs for 14.10 state that LIMIT is available and also for 12.10: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=statement-limit-clause

`SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 100` works.

Why it didn't work at first place, was due to internal peculiarities.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer explaining, exactly, what these "internal peculiarities" were?